# SSRS - Export to excel on different sheets without acting on on page breaks

Tags: excel, reporting-services

Given a report like that is it possible in any way to split those tables into different sheets  in excel without acting on the page breaks? I can't modify the print layout, so I can't change them. But I need those tablix to be each of them on a separete Excel sheets
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There may be a way to do this, although I've never tried it. This will only work on SSRS 2008R2 or later.

You could add a rectangle between each tablix and set it to page break after. Then you can set the visibility of this rectangle based on what the render format is. `Globals.RenderFormat.Name`

So, add the rectangle between the current Tablix then in the tablix properties change the hidden property to an expression something like this.

```
=SWITCH(
Globals!RenderFOrmat.Name = "PDF", True,
Globals!RenderFOrmat.Name = "RPL", True,
True, False
)
```

The above will hide the tablix for interactive viewing or PDF export and not hide it for other formats.

There are several render formats depending on the version of SSRS so it's best to add a text box temporarily and set its expression to `=Globals!RenderFormat.Name` then export to all relevant formats and see what the name for each is and adjust the SWITCH statement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the answer is no. SSRS only uses the page break property to create new sheets. In terms of a workaround, you could either have two versions of the report or you could add a parameter to choose whether or not to use the page breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I use this option:

1. On the Property Settings of the object you want to break on
2. Under the General section
3. Under the PageBreak
4. Set the BreakLocator - set that how you want in my case it is = "Start"
5. Then set the Disabled flag to an expression: in my case it is "=iif(LEFT(Globals!RenderFormat.Name,5) = "EXCEL", False, True)".

I only want the sheet breaks in EXCEL. This logic then disables the page break depending on the RendorFormat values. This works in version 2017.

[Image of Page Break Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WUxW.png)